# Get the new record primary key ID from SQL insert query to insert same value into another table?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have the following C#

```
protected void add_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string teamname = team_name_tb.Text;
    string teamstatus = "Not Started";
    string teamnotes = team_notes_tb.Text;
    string sprintid = sprint_select.SelectedValue;

    string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    myConnection.Open();

            String query = "INSERT INTO teams (team_name, status, notes) 
                            VALUES (@team_name, @status, @notes); 
                            INSERT INTO sprints_vs_teams (sprint_id, team_id)                    
                            VALUES (@sprint_id, @team_id)";

            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team_name", teamname);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", teamstatus);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", teamnotes);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sprint_id", sprintid);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team_id", ????);

            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myConnection.Close();
}
```

In the `teams` table the primary key is `team_id` I want to be able to pull the value of this and insert it into the `team_id` field in the lookup table I have `sprints_vs_teams`. Is there a method of doing this, if so could you possibly provide my with some guidance, please be aware I am very new to C#. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## Amended code

```
protected void add_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String user = Session["user_id"].ToString();
    string teamname = team_name_tb.Text;
    string teamstatus = "Not Started";
    string teamnotes = team_notes_tb.Text;
    string sprintid = sprint_select.SelectedValue;

string ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

myConnection.Open();

String query = "Declare @team_identity int INSERT INTO teams (team_name, status, notes) VALUES (@team_name, @status, @notes); set @team_identity = scope_identity() INSERT INTO sprints_vs_teams (sprint_id, team_id) VALUES (@sprint_id, @team_identity)";

       SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team_name", teamname);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", teamstatus);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@notes", teamnotes);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sprint_id", sprintid);

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
}
```

I amended my code with @Sick 's answer, however it didn't seem to work. If anyone could advise on where I may have went wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate on "it didn't seem to work". An error? No data inserted? The wrong data inserted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190315.aspx)

```
Declare @team_identity int

INSERT INTO teams (team_name, status, notes) 
                            VALUES (@team_name, @status, @notes);

set @team_identity = scope_identity()

INSERT INTO sprints_vs_teams (sprint_id, team_id)                    
                            VALUES (@sprint_id, @team_identity)"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I added this to my code although unfortunately it did not seem to work. I added my amended code to my question, could you possibly advise on where I may have went wrong?

Comment: @mcclosa - Please wrap these SQL statements into a SP and execute it.

Comment: @RahulSingh Sorry, as I mentioned in my question, I am very new to C# and programming in general so I am not sure how to do this. Could you provide me with some guidance?

Comment: @mcclosa - Hey it's very easy, please refer to siome basic tutorial, you will get many.

Comment: @RahulSingh I have had a look around but I am not sure how it links directly into what I am doing and where my code is currently incorrect. Is this a simple few lines of code or is it more intricate than that? Sorry again, complete newbie and I do not have a lot of time to complete this part of the project.

Comment: @mcclosa - Sorry I am a DB guy. I dont have any idea about C# code. But this should pull you the last generated Identity value

Comment: I got it figured out in the end, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you have to declare team_identity as a cmd.parameter. of course there is no param passed into it c# is still expecting one

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team_identity", ParameterDirection.Output);
```

Or something like that

Answer (score 0):

after inserting a row into `teams` table, write the following code to get the current value of identity and the use it during insert into `sprints_vs_teams` table.

```
SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select Ident_current('teams')",Cn);
Cn.Open();
int teamid=int.Parse(Cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Hope it helps